# How do I $filter outlook messages based on values stored in data Extensions?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I've just started using MSGraph, and I'm storing some custom data in Graph resources using the [Open Extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/opentypeextension?view=graph-rest-1.0) option. Now I want to get a list of those resources where the Extension contains custom property values (e.g. `DealValue = 50050`).

I've tried the following query in the Graph Explorer to get a list of messages:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages/
?$filter=Extensions/any(f:f/id eq 'testExtension' && f:f/DealValue eq '500050' )
&$expand=Extensions($filter=id eq 'testExtension')
```

I was hoping for list of message items that had a DealValue of 50050, but I get the following response:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "BadRequest",
        "message": "Invalid filter clause",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "...",
            "date": "2019-04-10T23:30:50"
        }
    }
}
```

2 Questions:

1. **Is it possible to $filter on embedded properties with Extensions?**
2. If not, what are my other options?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else visiting this question, I finally found the answer:

At the time of writing:

1. No, [it is not possible to filter on custom properties in Open Extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/known-issues#extensions).
2. [Use Schema Extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/extensibility-overview#) if you need to filter on custom properties

Comment: are you familiar with using the `select` parameter of the API?

Comment: @moegizzle, yes, I'm familiar with the `$select` parameter. This question is about the `$filter` parameter

Comment: could you also see the question I posted if you have a better understanding? I am facing an issue also using the Graph API.